# Specific XML Attribute values into Class List

Tags: c#, xml

Its been a while since I last tried to program and has never worked with XML before. I have a internal website that display XML

```
   <Source>
    <AllowsDuplicateFileNames>YES</AllowsDuplicateFileNames> 
    <Description>The main users ....</Description> 
    <ExportSWF>FALSE</ExportSWF> 
    <HasDefaultPublishDir>NO</HasDefaultPublishDir> 
    <Id>28577db1-956c-41f6-b775-a278c39e20a1</Id> 
    <IsAssociated>YES</IsAssociated> 
    <LogoURL>http://servername:8080/logos/9V0.png</LogoURL> 
    <Name>Portal1</Name> 
    <RequiredParameters>
     <RequiredParameter>
      <Id>user_name</Id> 
      <Name>UserID</Name> 
      <PlaceHolder>username</PlaceHolder> 
      <ShowAsDescription>true</ShowAsDescription> 
     </RequiredParameter>
   </RequiredParameters>
```

I don't want the values in the child tags, there is time where there will be more than one portal thus the need/want to use a list. I only need the values inside of the Name and ID tags. also if there is a blank ID tag I don't want to store the either one of them.

My current approach to this is not working as expected:

```
String URLString = "http://servername:8080/roambi/SourceManager";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);

List<Portal> lPortals = new List<Portal>();
String sPortal = "";
String sId = "";

while (reader.Read())
{
    //Get Portal ID
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Id")
    {
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            sId = reader.Value;
        }
    }

    //Get Portal Name
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Name")
    {
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            sPortal = reader.Value;
        }

        //Fill Portal List with Name and ID
        if (sId != "" && sPortal != "")
        {
            lPortals.Add(new Portal
            {
                Portalname = sPortal,
                Portalid = sId
            });
        }
    }
}

foreach (Portal i in lPortals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Portalname + " " + i.Portalid);
}
```

See my standard class

```
class Portal 
{
    private String portalname;
    private String portalid;

    public String Portalname
    {
        get { return portalname; }
        set { portalname = value; }
    }

    public String Portalid
    {
        get { return portalid; }
        set { portalid = value; }
    }
}
```

Please give me some advice and point me into a direction, As I said its been a while since I last programmed. My current Output is as follow:

```
Portal1 28577db1-956c-41f6-b775-a278c39e20a1
UserID user_name
```

UserID is in a child node and I do not want to display child nodes

Comment: http://servername:8080/roambi/SourceManager.xml....?

Comment: Just the path to the web application, not important.

Comment: i mean .xml extension,did you forget to put it here in the sample or is like that in your code

Comment: the server outputs xml to the browser, using the XmlTextReader I can access is perfectly. If I replace `sPortal = reader.Value;` with `Console.WriteLine(reader.value);` I get the XML output into the console

Comment: you then want to get the innertext of the node if thats the case you can use reader.ReadContentAsString(),but value should also work

Comment: See my output, I almost get what I want, but not completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier with [**XDocument**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class:

```
String URLString = "http://servername:8080/roambi/SourceManager";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

// assuming there's some root-node whose children are Source nodes
var portals = doc.Root
    .Elements("Source")
    .Select(source => new Portal
        {
            Portalname = (string) source.Element("Name"),
            Portalid = (string) source.Element("Id")
        })
    .Where(p => p.Portalid != "")
    .ToList();
```

For each `<Source>` node in your XML, code above will select direct children nodes (`<Name>` and `<Id>`) and build appropriate `Portal` instances.